# Update Increment Row Number on Group MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE PickSequence(
    [PickItemCode] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [PickSequence] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
)

INSERT INTO PickSequence (PickItemCode, PickSequence) VALUES ('695D-CV',1)
INSERT INTO PickSequence (PickItemCode, PickSequence) VALUES ('695D-CV',2)
INSERT INTO PickSequence (PickItemCode, PickSequence) VALUES ('695D-CV',3)
INSERT INTO PickSequence (PickItemCode, PickSequence) VALUES ('695D-CV',NULL)
INSERT INTO PickSequence (PickItemCode, PickSequence) VALUES ('695D-CV',NULL)
INSERT INTO PickSequence (PickItemCode, PickSequence) VALUES ('695D-CV',NULL)

INSERT INTO PickSequence (PickItemCode, PickSequence) VALUES ('695C-CV',NULL)
INSERT INTO PickSequence (PickItemCode, PickSequence) VALUES ('695C-CV',NULL)
INSERT INTO PickSequence (PickItemCode, PickSequence) VALUES ('695C-CV',NULL)
INSERT INTO PickSequence (PickItemCode, PickSequence) VALUES ('695C-CV',NULL)
INSERT INTO PickSequence (PickItemCode, PickSequence) VALUES ('695C-CV',NULL)

SELECT PickItemCode, PickSequence FROM PickSequence ORDER BY PickItemCode, PickSequence

| PickItemCode | PickSequence |
|:------------:|--------------|
| 695D-CV      | 1            |
| 695D-CV      | 2            |
| 695D-CV      | 3            |
| 695D-CV      | NULL         |
| 695D-CV      | NULL         |
| 695D-CV      | NULL         |
| 695C-CV      | NULL         |
| 695C-CV      | NULL         |
| 695C-CV      | NULL         |
| 695C-CV      | NULL         |
| 695C-CV      | NULL         |
```

The output im looking for below

```
| PickItemCode | PickSequence |
|:------------:|--------------|
| 695D-CV      | 1            |
| 695D-CV      | 2            |
| 695D-CV      | 3            |
| 695D-CV      | 4            |
| 695D-CV      | 5            |
| 695D-CV      | 6            |
| 695C-CV      | 1            |
| 695C-CV      | 2            |
| 695C-CV      | 3            |
| 695C-CV      | 4            |
| 695C-CV      | 5            |
```

With the code below I was able to query the table creating the sequence number im looking for but not sure how to have it look at the highest value for that PartItemCode.

```
SELECT PickItemCode,
    PickSequence = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PickItemCode ORDER BY PickItemCode) ,
    [Part_Index] = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY PickItemCode)
FROM PickSequence
```

What im looking to do is update the PickSequence value with the next number in the sequence grouped by the PickItemCode.

Comment: uhm...what?, can you clarify what you want as a result?

Comment: Something like `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PickItemCode ORDER BY CASE WHEN PickSequence IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, PickSequence)`?

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: I've updated the question to better reflect. hope that helps

Comment: Thanks ZLK I was able to figure out how to get the correct select statement with adding the CASE statement in the ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE UpdateTarget 
SET PickSequence = NewSequence
FROM
(
    SELECT PickSequence,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PickItemCode ORDER BY CASE WHEN PickSequence IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, PickSequence) as NewSequence
    FROM PickSequence
) as UpdateTarget
```